# Writing high volume reducer output to HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have an Hadoop MapReduce job whose output is a row-id with a Put/Delete operation for that row-id. Due to the nature of the problem, the output is rather high volume. We have tried several method to get this data back into HBase and they have all failed...

**Table Reducer**

This is way to slow since it seems that it must do a full round trip for every row. Due to how the keys sort for our reducer step, the row-id is not likely to be on the same node as the reducer.

**completebulkload**

This seems to take a long time (never completes) and there is no real indication of why. Both IO and CPU show very low usage.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: in my opinion figuring out why completebulkload isn't working would be the right thing to do. it should work! also, you could have more reducers perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CompleteBulkLoad was the right answer. Per @DonaldMiner I dug deeper and found out that the CompleteBulkLoad process was running as "hbase" which resulted in a permission denied error when trying to move/rename/delete the source files. The implementation appears to retry for a *long* time before giving an error message; up to 30 minutes in our case.

Giving the hbase user write access to the files resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I saw from your answer to self that you solved your problem but for completeness I'd mention that there's another option - writing directly to hbase. We have a set up where we stream data into HBase and  with proper key and region splitting we get to more than 15,000 1K records per second per node

Comment: Our reducer by it's very nature will have keys from many regions per input split. If you know of some post-reducer hbase splitter method please share it.

Comment: As I said we do our updates in a streaming setup not a batch one - but the principle still holds you can create a regular hbase connection in the reducer and still write to hbase efficiently if you design your hbase correctly , write in batches, tune your hbase etc. :) - If working with BulkLoad is good enough for you then it is probably simpler